# how to concate two tensors with different dimensions in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have two tensors in pytorch with these shapes:

> torch.Size([64, 100]) and torch.Size([64, 100, 256])

I want to concate them by `torch.cat` but they should be in the same shape and size. So I get this error:

> RuntimeError: Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 2 and 3

what should I do to fix this problem? how can I convert 2d PyTorch tensor into 3d tensor OR how can I convert 3d PyTorch tensor to 2d tensor without losing any data? or any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are looking to do with those two tensors, you could consider concatenating on the last axis such that the resulting tensor is shaped `(64, 100, 257)`. This requires you first unsqueeze a singleton dimensions on the first tensor:

```
>>> x, y = torch.rand(64, 100), torch.rand(64, 100, 256)
>>> z = torch.cat((x[..., None], y), -1)

>>> z.shape
torch.Size([64, 100, 257])
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer actually works, though I don't understand it fully!

Comment: To concatenate two tensors, you need them to have the same number of dimensions and identical sizes on all dimensions *except* the one you are concatenating on. In this case, I am adding an extra (3rd and last) dimension to x.