# how to solve "RuntimeError: Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 2 and 1"?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to train a Conditional Generative Adversarial Networks (CGANs) on MNIST dataset. To make the code easier to debug I used a function for a training loop. Everything seems just write to me. However, once calling the training loop function, I get an error like `RuntimeError: Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 2 and 1` which I tried to solve by `unsqueeze` for `y`. But it wasn't as helpful.

what is the issue, and what is the trick to resolve it?

Here's my code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F

from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from torchvision.utils import make_grid

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# the generator network
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim, output_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(latent_dim + 10, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 512)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512, 1024)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(1024, output_dim)

    def forward(self, x, y):
        x = torch.cat([x, y], dim=1)
        x = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)(self.fc1(x))
        x = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)(self.fc2(x))
        x = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)(self.fc3(x))
        x = torch.tanh(self.fc4(x))
        return x

# the discriminator network
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim + 10, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 1)

    def forward(self, x, y):
        y = y.unsqueeze(1)  # reshape y to have shape (batch_size, 1, height, width)
        x = torch.cat([x, y], dim=1)  # concatenate x and y along the second dimension

        x = torch.cat([x, y], dim=1)
        x = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)(self.fc1(x))
        x = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)(self.fc2(x))
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc3(x))
        return x

# the CGAN class
class CGAN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim, input_dim, output_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.generator = Generator(latent_dim, output_dim)
        self.discriminator = Discriminator(input_dim)

    def forward(self, x, y):
        fake_imgs = self.generator(x, y)
        preds = self.discriminator(fake_imgs, y)
        return preds, fake_imgs


# Define the training loop
def train(model, dataloader, num_epochs, device, latent_dim, lr):
    optimizer_d = optim.Adam(model.discriminator.parameters(), lr=lr)
    optimizer_g = optim.Adam(model.generator.parameters(), lr=lr)
    criterion = nn.BCELoss()

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for i, (imgs, labels) in enumerate(dataloader):
            real_imgs = imgs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)

            # Train the discriminator
            optimizer_d.zero_grad()
            z = torch.randn(real_imgs.size(0), latent_dim).to(device)
            fake_imgs = model.generator(z, labels)
            real_preds = model.discriminator(real_imgs, labels)
            fake_preds = model.discriminator(fake_imgs.detach(), labels)
            loss_d = criterion(real_preds, torch.ones_like(real_preds)) + criterion(fake_preds, torch.zeros_like(fake_preds))
            loss_d.backward()
            optimizer_d.step()

            # Train the generator
            optimizer_g.zero_grad()
            z = torch.randn(real_imgs.size(0), latent_dim).to(device)
            fake_imgs = model.generator(z, labels)
            fake_preds = model.discriminator(fake_imgs, labels)
            loss_g = criterion(fake_preds, torch.ones_like(fake_preds))

            loss_g.backward()
            optimizer_g.step()

            # Print the loss after each epoch
            print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Discriminator loss: {loss_d.item():.4f}, Generator loss: {loss_g.item():.4f}")

            # Generate 15 images and save them
            with torch.no_grad():
              z = torch.randn(15, latent_dim).to(device)
              labels = torch.LongTensor(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=15)).to(device)
              fake_imgs = model.generator(z, labels)
              img_grid = make_grid(fake_imgs, nrow=5, normalize=True)
              plt.imshow(img_grid.permute(1, 2, 0).cpu().numpy())
              plt.axis('off')
              plt.show()


# Set the hyperparameters and load the data

batch_size = 128
latent_dim = 100
input_dim = 784
output_dim = 784
num_epochs = 50
lr = 0.0002
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

transform = transforms.Compose([
transforms.ToTensor(),
transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
])

train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root="./data", train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# Create an instance of the CGAN model and train it
model = CGAN(latent_dim, input_dim, output_dim).to(device)
train(model, train_dataloader, num_epochs, device, latent_dim, lr)
```

The Error is also like the following:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

      1 # Create an instance of the CGAN model and train it
      2 model = CGAN(latent_dim, input_dim, output_dim).to(device)
----> 3 train(model, train_dataloader, num_epochs, device, latent_dim, lr)

2 frames
      9 
     10     def forward(self, x, y):
---> 11         x = torch.cat([x, y], dim=1)
     12         x = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)(self.fc1(x))
     13         x = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)(self.fc2(x))

RuntimeError: Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 2 and 1
```

Comment: What are the shapes of `imgs` and `labels`?

Comment: I'm using MNIST, so, image are the size if it and labels are batch size

Comment: I had similar problem and this answer worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259289/how-to-concate-two-tensors-with-different-dimensions-in-pytorch

Answer (score 2):

From your code, I believe your `imgs` is of dimension `batch X 784`, whereas your `labels` has dimensions `batch X 1`. You cannot use `torch.cat` with parameters of different dimensions (in this case dimension 1). You can try to concat using the `nn.Embedding` layer as shown [here](https://github.com/qbxlvnf11/conditional-GAN/blob/main/conditional-GAN-generating-fashion-mnist.ipynb)

Comment: Can you explain the motivation for using an `nn.Embedding`?

Comment: Class labels would be digits in its original form. You'd want a vector for concatenation with your input. One way to do this would be to add random noise to your labels with same dimension as input. This usually forces the generator to learn same/similar images for a given class without variety. nn.Embedding is alternate approach which handles this issue. According to [this](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/keras-understanding-the-role-of-embedding-layer-in-a-conditional-gan), it stores a state for each label which are then used to concatenate with the input.